# Generate Video in C# using Microsoft Expression Encoder and a series of bitmaps

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-encoding, expression-encoder-sdk

I need to generate a video in C#. I am messing around with Microsoft Expression Encoder but what I have is a series of bitmaps at specific time indices. Is there a way to use the Microsoft Expression Encoder to encode a video using a series of bitmaps as I have described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It CAN be done, but Expression Encoder isn't the right way to do it.

[From a Microsoft employee in their forums](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/a6ff6437-8ff6-4698-8791-ab96a4c549ba):

> This technique is called "time-lapse" or "stop-motion" and
>   unfortunately Expression Encoder by itself isn't the right tool. You
>   could use an AVSynth script as a source for Encoder if you want, but
>   other tailored products to do this will just get you better results.

and [further from the same employee here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/6c12be0b-8b7b-4c39-849d-46ea166c761d/):

> Unfortunately, Encoder doesn't directly support this scenario. Our
>   pipeline just isn't built to deal with that many input files. There
>   might be a way to do this with AVISynth (which we do support),
>   otherwise it's likely that you'll need to use 3rd party tool to create
>   a video file we can import. Besides using QTP, looks like people
>   trying to do this are using Adobe AfterEffects to do this. Others are
>   using freewares, like Photo Lapse 3 or VirtualDub.